# Graph states: two equivalent definitions

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-mechanics, algebraic-graph-theory, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I know two definitions of graph states:

- $|G\rangle = K^{a} |G\rangle = \sigma_x^{a} \otimes \sigma_z^{b} |G\rangle$ for all $a \in V$ vertices and for all $b\in Na$ connected to $a$ through an edge.
- $|G\rangle = \Pi_{a,b} Cz^{(a,b)} |+\rangle$ where $a,b$ are the same as before, Cz is a controlled $\sigma_z$, and $|+\rangle = |0\rangle + |1\rangle$ (ignoring normalization)

I would like to prove their equivalence. It's easy to show that the second implies the first one, but I have no idea on how to prove the other arrow. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

check this [page](https://www.hashpi.com/quantum-graph-states-two-equivalent-definitions), based on [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602096) paper.